# simple function, how to add to global path?

Tags: python, function, path, call, pythonpath

I am trying to build out a set of custom functions I can reference in any .py file for my research project.

If I place a very simple function in `D:\_coding\pyfun`, how can I get Python to reference this directory in all of my future scripts - so I can call the functions living there? My IDE is PyCharm if that matters.

e.g., 
`add.py` is saved in `D:\_coding\pyfun`

```
def add(a, b):
    return a+b
```

And now when I call in Python, of course it doesn't recognize add

```
>     add(1,3)
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
>     NameError: name 'add' is not defined
```

Comment: You need ti *import* it. How did you run the shell?

Answer (score 1):

You can *import* it. For example with:

```
$ python3
Python 3.6.6 (default, Sep 12 2018, 18:26:19) 
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from add import add
>>> add(1, 3)
4
```

Note that the working directory of the interpreter needs to be in the same directory as where the `add.py` file is located.

If this is not the case, you first need to specify that the directories are modules by adding an (empty) `__init__.py` file.

You can also add the directory where your `add.py` file is located in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. This is a colon-separted string that contains paths where the Python interpreter will look when looking to import a module.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to edit the PYTHONPATH variable, you can add the folder manually in the python script itself, as follows:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('D:\_coding\pyfun')
import Yourpackage.pyfile
```